# Not able to set background color to header with css file

Tags: html, css

I am not able to set background color to header with css file for some reason. What could be the problem?

This is what I am doing:

## css code

```
*{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

 .body {


    font-family: tahoma;

 }
 .one{

    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    top: 30%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }

 .header
{
  background-color: red;

}
```

## Html code

```
  <title> flex </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
   <header>
   <div class="one">
   <h1>Finally a <br> healthcare plan <br> that rewards you </h1>
   <div>
   </header>
```

Comment: Can you show your header code from html?

Comment: <html>
<head> 

      <title> flex </title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<head>

<body>


       <header>
       <div class="one">
       <h1>Finally a <br> healthcare plan <br> that rewards you </h1>
       <div>
       </header>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class selector (the `.` before header) for your header in the CSS. `<header>` is an element not a class.

Answer (score 0):

In your css you have `.header`

In your html you have a `<header>`

The '.' signifies a class.

You should change your html to `<header class="header">`

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong syntax for CSS. `.header` would style an element that has been defined a class name of 'header'. To style your header **element**, you need to use: `header{background-color: red;}`

Answer (score -1):

Try following things:
1. Clear your browser cache. This happened to me couple of times, the browser caches the .css files and displays older versions.
2. Check spelling to make sure .css can find element with a "header" class
3. Check if you connected html and css file with

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "style.css">
```